# Swift: How to convert a particle network JS animation to iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I found this javascript animation:
[JS animation](https://blog.alexwendland.com/2015/particle-network-js-animations/)

I really want to know how I can convert animations like this to use it in my Swift iOS app. 
Has anybody got experience in likely things? I found things like spritekit, but I really can't find the right info/tutorials about this.

Maybe someone does know what I should do/look up?

Hope anybody can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use CGPaths to help setup your network,  you can then run SKActions along the path

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for your reaction, I searched for info of CGPaths earlier, but I really don't know how to form suck a network from it. SKActions wouldn't be the problem, but could you help me start up with the network or do you have any examples? Can't find very much about it...

Comment: You add points to your CGPath that look exactly like the network you have provided

Comment: Are you trying to make that exact animation in that link or something similar?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Doesn't have to me exact, but I want it to be something like it. The most important thing is dat the network of dots is connected with lines what moves like that in the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a customView to upgrade their js codes to swift. Hope it is the answer. Beware of the copyright when you use their codes in this way.  It's just for a demo.

In details, circle class is needed here to represent their points. In storyboard, assign a UIView to MyView and you can get the result.

```
class Circle : NSObject {
var position: CGPoint!
var speed : CGPoint!
init(position: CGPoint, speed: CGPoint) {
    super.init()
    self.position = position
    self.speed = speed
}
}

class MyView : UIView{
var balls: [Circle] = []

override func  didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
    contentMode = .redraw
    clipsToBounds = false
    func randomValue () -> CGFloat {
      let upperBound : UInt32 = 1000;
      return (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(upperBound))) / CGFloat(upperBound);
    }
    let array = (0..<Int(bounds.width*bounds.height / (65*65))).map { _ in
        Circle.init(position: CGPoint.init(x: bounds.width * randomValue() , y: bounds.height * randomValue()), speed: CGPoint.init(x: randomValue() * 2 - 1 , y:randomValue() * 2 - 1) ) }
    balls.append(contentsOf: array)
 let    displayLink =  CADisplayLink.init(target: self, selector: #selector(update(_:)))
    displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
}

@objc  func update(_ sender : CADisplayLink){
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    _ = (0..<(balls.count)).map{
        let circle =  balls[$0]
        if (circle.position.x > rect.size.width + 50 || circle.position.x < -50) {
            circle.speed.x = -circle.speed.x;
        }
        if (circle.position.y > rect.size.height + 50 || circle.position.y < -50) {
            circle.speed.y = -circle.speed.y;
        }
        circle.position.x += circle.speed.x;
        circle.position.y += circle.speed.y;
    }
    let color = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0x1c / 255 , blue: 0x33 / 255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    ctx.setFillColor(color )
    ctx.fill(rect)

    _ = (0..<(balls.count)).map{
        let ball = balls[$0];
        ctx.beginPath()
        let color = UIColor.init(red: 0x44 / 255 , green: 0x8f / 255 , blue: 0xda / 255, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
        ctx.setFillColor(color)
        ctx.addArc( center: ball.position , radius: 3.0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: false)
        ctx.fillPath()
        ctx.beginPath();
        var index2 = balls.count - 1
        while (index2 > $0 ){
            let ball2 = balls[index2];
            let dist =   hypot(ball.position.x - ball2.position.x  , ball.position.y - ball2.position.y );
            if (dist < 100) {
                ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.init(red: 0x44 / 255, green: 0x8f / 255, blue: 0xda / 255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor )
                ctx.setAlpha( 1 - (dist > 100 ? 0.8 : dist / 150) )
                ctx.setLineWidth(2);
                ctx.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0.5 + ball.position.x, y: 0.5 + ball.position.y))
                ctx.addLine(to:  CGPoint.init(x: 0.5 + ball2.position.x, y: 0.5 + ball2.position.y))
            }
            index2 -= 1;
        }
        ctx.strokePath()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Using SpriteKit, To make the animation in that link you provided, I would create a loop that generates N number of dots (SKSpriteNodes) randomly placed on the scene.  Then recursively move each dot to a new random location.  Then, in the `update()` function of the scene, loop over all the dots and run some calculations to determine if dot X is within so many points of any other dot on the scene and create a CGPath between those two. And remove that CGPath if is not.